Europass CV \href in personal info
I'm trying to use \href command in the homepage \ecvhomepage section of EuropassCV. Following is a MWE:
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[english,a4paper,nologo,notitle]{europasscv}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,  
    urlcolor=ecvrulecolor,
}
\ecvname{First name, Last name}
\begin{document}
    \begin{europasscv}
        \ecvpersonalinfo
        \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX}
    \end{europasscv}
\end{document}

This works as expected but as soon as I enter the line \ecvhomepage{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX}}, I get several runaway errors.
According to the answer here it should be okay to use \href inside \ecvhomepage.

the other answer uses a different class. This here clearly does not handle commands inside the argument, and sadly it uses http instead of https by default. Contact the author if you want additional features.
